# Communication between Host and Server with completely different sshmac/sshcipher

Tags: ssh, encryption, openssh, sshd

I have a little bit idea about sshcipher and sshmac.

Recently i got to know that to change sshmac and sshcipher , we need to update sshd_config with required cipher/mac.

Now the question here is :
Suppose there is a Host which is having a set of sshciphers and there is a client who is trying to establish a ssh connection to this host and the client is having completely different sshciphers set in sshd_config. There is 0 intersection between the sshciphers of Client and Host. With 0 intersection also Client is able to remotely establish ssh connection, how is it possible ?

Is it possible to restrict those clients to establish ssh connection who have 0 intersection with host.

I hope that I was able to clearly describe my question .

Answer (score 0):

> With 0 intersection also Client is able to remotely establish ssh connection, how is it possible ?

No, it is not possible. Post the verbose log of the connection (`ssh -vvv host`) to see that there is some intersection.

Comment: Googled a bit more and found out that sshd is the daemon which runs on a server and allows others to connect to the machine and ssh is used by the clients for establishing connection to remote machines.

I guess that means , there should be zero intersection between client's ssh_config and server's sshd_config.

Got to know about the difference between ssh/sshd from :
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1261552

Do you also agree with my understanding or I misunderstood it ?
Thanks and Appreciate your response/help.

Comment: Quite yes, if you are trying to say, that there are two separate programs with different configuration files.